# What is the slope of the line tangent to the surface at that point $(2,-1)$ lying in the plane $y=-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, 3d

> For the function $f(x,y)=x(x+y^5)$,What is the slope of the line
>   tangent to the surface at that point $(2,-1)$ lying in the plane
>   $y=-1$?

I know how to find the linear approximation of any function,but i'm not getting any approach of finding the slope.

Please suggest any method/formula....

Comment: Think directional derivative.

Comment: @amd:Here,we have the theorem:Let $f(x,y)$ is a function that is differentiable at $P(x_0,y_0)$.Then $f$ has a  directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $u=u_1i+u_2j$ is given by  $D_uf(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)u_1+f_y(x_0,y_0)u_2$.I wanted to confirm $u$.Is it $u=-j$?

Comment: No. What is the intersection of the $y=-1$ plane with the $x$-$y$ plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plane is parallel to the $z$-axis, this question is basically asking you about a directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(2,-1)$. For this plane, $y$ is constant, so the particular directional derivative required is just the partial $x$-derivative of $f$ at this point ($\nabla f\cdot (1,0)=f_x$). I expect that you’ll be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y^5$ if y = -1 (is constant), $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x-1$, so the slope of the intersection curve generated by f(x, y) and the plane y = -1 at (2, -1) is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{x=2}=3$.
If you keep y = -1, the function is only going to change along the X axis, that gives the intersection curve with the plane y = -1, so use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y_0^5$ if y keeps constant.

Comment: :Is the answer 3??